# python- GLM Poisson Regression Probabilities

Tags: python, machine-learning, statsmodels

I am using Statsmodel GLM model to perform a poisson regression. I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
    Quantity  Month  cannibal_numbers  category_performance
0        0.0     11                 0                     7
1     3985.0      1                 1                     2
2     7690.0      2                 5                     4
3    10070.0      4                 3                    10
```

`Quantity` is the predicted variable and the 3 other columns are the predictors.

Quantity is the predicted variable and the 3 other columns are the predictors.

following the Statsmodels documentation, I built the poisson regression model this way:

```
expr = """Quantity ~ Month  + cannibal_numbers + category_performance"""
        y, X = dmatrices(expr, series, return_type='dataframe')

poisson_fit = sm.GLM(y, X, family=sm.families.Poisson()).fit()

poisson_predict = poisson_fit.predict()
```

I am stuck here. What I want to get is the probability that `Quantity` will be 1, 2, 3 etc.. until n. I have no clue on how to achieve this.

How could this be done in statsmodels? Thank you in advance for any guidance
UPDATE: thanks to Josef, things are a bit more clearer, tweaking my model as he suggested:

```
poisson_fit = sm.GLM(y, X, family=sm.families.Poisson()).fit()
    series['poisson_predict'] = poisson_fit.predict()


    counts = np.arange(4)
    predict_prob = stats.poisson.pmf(counts, np.asarray(series['poisson_predict'])[:, None])
    results = pd.DataFrame(predict_prob)
```

returns a probability of occurence of quantity = 1 to 4 for each row of the dataset. As follow:

```
              0             1             2             3             4   \
0   9.267928e-08  1.500859e-06  1.215255e-05  6.559995e-05  2.655834e-04   
1   9.267928e-08  1.500859e-06  1.215255e-05  6.559995e-05  2.655834e-04   
2   9.267928e-08  1.500859e-06  1.215255e-05  6.559995e-05  2.655834e-04   
3   2.286170e-07  3.495832e-06  2.672777e-05  1.362334e-04  5.207935e-04 
...
```

Wouldn't fitting the model give me the equation line for this data (including mu) and so that predicting the probability of occurence of `quantities` from 1 to 4, would be done by taking into consideration this equation, thus resulting in a only one probability per demand quantity?

Answer (score 1):

The Poisson model in statsmodels.discrete has `predict_prob` method in the results instance to compute this.

https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/master/statsmodels/discrete/discrete_model.py#L3900

For Poisson, we can just use the scipy.stats distribution directly, the parameterization is the same.

For example, using numpy broadcasting to get probabilities for 0, ... 4 in columns for all predicted cases in rows

```
from scipy import stats
poisson_predict = poisson_fit.predict()
counts = np.arange(5)
predict_prob = stats.poisson.pmf(counts, np.asarray(poisson_predict)[:, None])
```

In some other GLM and count distributions like negative binomial, the parameterization for the regression model differs from the parameterization in scipy. We need to transform the parameters to make them consistent with the scipy.stats.distributions parameterization.

Some newer count model like GeneralizedPoisson and the zero-inflated versions have a "which" option in predict that can return predicted probabilities directly.

e.g. for ZeroInflated Models

```
which str, optional
    Define values that will be predicted. 
    ‘mean’, ‘mean-main’, ‘linear’, ‘mean-nonzero’, 
    ‘prob-zero, ‘prob’, ‘prob-main’ Default is ‘mean’.
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer, it is unvaluable help! I am still confused about something, why the result of ```poisson_predict``` is used as ```mu``` in the distribution generation?

Comment: The parameter of the Poisson distribution is `mu` which is equal to the mean of the distribution. The predict method returns the prediction for the mean which therefore corresponds to the poisson parameter mu (or sometimes called lambda)

Comment: Thanks Josef, I have a lot to learn, then why passing ```poisson predict``` as the mu in your example, i feel like a mu for each value of historical dataset?